# Counting zeroes using Recursion and if-else in python

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

```
def countz(n):
    if n<10:
        if n==0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    small=countz(n//10)
    if n%10==0:
        return small+1
    else:
        return small


from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(11000)
n = int(input())
print(countz(n))
```

Someone helped me write  this code, I did not understand why he used the condition n<10 in the base case of the recursion. I though the code would work without that condition but it didn't. Can anyone help me understand why the code is not working without that condition/ what is the real purpose or reason for that condition?

Comment: The clue is that the condition will fire when n is a single digit number.

Comment: btw, the two ‘else:’ lines are redundant since the line before is a ‘return’.

Comment: What would happen without it if n is 206, or 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base case that we want here is indeed `n<10`, or in words, `n` is a single digit number.

You might be tempted to choose `n==0` as the base case and simply `return 1` because it has one zero:

```py
def countz(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    small=countz(n//10)
    if n%10==0:
        return small+1
    else:
        return small
```

But that wouldn't work! Why? Consider the input `9`, which has no zeroes. This isn't the base case, so we enter the recursive call: `small=countz(n//10)`. `n//10` gives `0`, so we call `countz(0)` which returns `1`. This is then returned as the answer, even though it should be `0`.

The underlying problem is that, by convention, we denote the number zero with one more digit than is actually needed. Ideally it would consist of no digits at all, but that would be a bit impractical in daily life!